# Entity Framework 5 - Code First - Inserting Identity Value?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an entity with a PK defined that is an Identity column in the underlying database. In most cases, I just let SQL Server generate the value for me. However, in certain cases I want to provide a value instead of SQL Server generating one. Am I able to do this with EF 5 (using Code First)?

Comment: The SQL side of it is handled by Set Identity_insert
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509564/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-set-primary-key-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is SQL Server, then send the commands you need using ExecuteSQLCommand

I created this test as an example

```
 [Fact]
        private void IdentityInsertOK()
        {
            var sql = "set identity_insert  ConfigSettings on " +
                       "delete from ConfigSettings where id =2 " +
                      "insert into ConfigSettings (Id,Name, value) values (2,'test ','testval')  " +
                      "set identity_insert  ConfigSettings off ";
            using (var Db = SettingsHelper.CreateContext(ConnectionType.Syrius))
            {
                Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```