# IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate not setting ID in database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework Code First's Seed method, I have been making calls like this to add new objects to a table.

`private void SeedDatabaseActivities(SiteDbContext context)
    {
            context.Activities.AddOrUpdate(new ActivityDefinition
            {
                Id = 605,
                Name = "bicycling, >20 mph, racing, not drafting",
                UseSteps = false,
                UseDistance = false,
                Category = "bicycling",
                Mets = 16
            }); 
}`

This was working great for months.  Recently, this no longer sets the ID, correctly. I have been searching for why this would change, but haven't been able to find the issue.

What would cause this behavior?

Comment: Try adding the key: AddOrUpdate(ad => ad.Id, new ActivityDefinition {...});   http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Comment: @SteveGreene, I've seen that page, and it's on the right track, but the difference is in that example, they're setting the Name property, and not the Id property.

Comment: Is your Id field defined as identity?

Comment: Yes, it's identified as Identity by using the DataAnnotation [Key].  Sometime between now and 6 months ago, this was valid to insert an ID into that column using the AddOrUpdate method but not the Add method. Neither works now, even when I explicedly run SQL that would allow it such as SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TABLE] ON

Comment: Have you tried [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509564/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-set-primary-key-value

Comment: @SteveGreene, I have. While that allows me to do the insert, these IDs are intended to be auto-increment. The only exception is the set that I'm adding to the DB at init time.